# Alternative to window["onYouTubePlayerAPIReady"]

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Is there an alternative to `window["onYouTubePlayerAPIReady"]`? I need to execute a function if the youTube Player API is ready but `window["onYouTubePlayerAPIReady"]` is already in use from another script which can not be modified.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Alright, i'll keep that in mind for my next question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple declarations of `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` functions the previous function will be overwritten and never be called.

The alternative solution is keep a reference on the first `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` function, then inside your own or second `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` function call the  function reference you kept.

```
setTimeout( function() {
    if ( typeof window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady !== 'undefined' ) {
        if ( typeof window.gambitOtherYTAPIReady === 'undefined' ) {
            window.gambitOtherYTAPIReady = [];
        }
        window.gambitOtherYTAPIReady.push( window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady );
    }
    window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {

        // Initialize YT.Player and do stuff here

        if ( typeof window.gambitOtherYTAPIReady !== 'undefined' ) {
            if ( window.gambitOtherYTAPIReady.length ) {
                window.gambitOtherYTAPIReady.pop()();
            }
        }
    }
```

Check this [page](http://www.gambit.ph/how-to-use-the-javascript-youtube-api-across-multiple-plugins/) for more information.